Lost Connection to the Rdp Server
Can anyone help me?
When I try to connect to an RDP Server, it says lost connection to the rdp server.
I use remmina on ubuntu.
How can I fix this issue ,I searched everything online but nothing works.
I´ve tried changing tne security setting and more but nothing works
or are there any alternatives?
My connecton is Vmworkstation -> Tor+Vpn-> Remmina->and then i have a problem setting it up
Please help

Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is the RDP server using Linux? Íf so, which one?

Same problem. I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on both computers with both on same network. RDP Server  on the host is configured using standard Ubuntu Settings app: both Remote Desktop Sharing & Remote Control set. Hostname is Laptop with Port 3389. Port 3389 has Port Forwarding for 3389 on Router to the appropriate reserved DHCP ip address.
Any ideas please?
